# Positioning the Cursor on the Screen

Tags: c++

Been at this for hours and cannot figure out how to get this the way I want.

I need it to center the text in the console output like this...

```
*******************************************
            ABC Industries
                Report
*******************************************
```

instead its coming out like this..

```
    **********************************
ABC Industries
Report
    **********************************
```

Here is what I got so far, any help will be gladly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

class Heading
{
private:
    string companyName;
    string reportName;
public:
    Heading();
    void placeCursor(HANDLE, int, int);
    void printStars(int);
    void getData(HANDLE, Heading&);
    void displayReport(HANDLE, Heading);
};

int main()
{
    Heading display;
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    display.getData(screen, display);
    display.displayReport(screen, display);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

Heading::Heading()
{
    companyName = "ABC Industries";
    reportName = "Report";
}

void Heading::placeCursor(HANDLE screen, int row, int col)
{
    COORD position;
    position.Y = row;
    position.X = col;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
}

void Heading::printStars(int n)
{
    for(int star=1; star<=n; star++)
        cout << '*';
    cout <<endl;
}

void Heading:: getData(HANDLE screen, Heading &input)
{
    string str;
    placeCursor(screen, 2, 5);
    cout <<"Enter company name";
    placeCursor(screen, 2, 26);
    getline(cin, str);

    if(str!="")
        input.companyName = str;
    placeCursor(screen, 4, 5);
    cout<<"enter report name";
    placeCursor(screen, 4, 26);
    getline(cin, str);
    if(str!="")
        input.reportName = str;
}

void Heading::displayReport(HANDLE screen, Heading input)
{
    int l;
    placeCursor(screen, 8, 5);
    printStars(69);
    string str=input.companyName;
    l= str.length();
    l=39-l/2;
    placeCursor(screen, 9, 1);
    cout << str;
    str=input.reportName;
    l=str.length();
    l=39-l/2;
    placeCursor(screen, 10, 1);
    cout << str;
    placeCursor(screen, 11, 5);
    printStars(69);
}
```

Comment: `std::setw` not working out for you (or repeated spaces)? Setting the cursor position seems a bit unnecessary, though I guess you can't tell how wide the console is with standard C++ anyway.

Comment: Note how you positioned the text in your expected output in this question.  You simply typed enough spaces beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to kick yourself..

Notice in Heading::displayReport, you calculate the length of the company name, then you divide it by 2 and subtract from 39. You then go on to position the cursor to 9,1 (nine, one).

What you meant to do was set the cursor position to 9,l (nine, el).

You then repeat the oversight for the reportName field too. ;-p

So, make these 2 change

```
//    placeCursor(screen, 9, 1);
    placeCursor(screen, 9, l);
```

and

```
//    placeCursor(screen, 10, 1);
    placeCursor(screen, 10, l);
```